# How to animate a cursor image when click in canvas area?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have changed my cursor to an own image, and I want to rotate the image `-120deg` when I click in the canvas area.

here is the animation I want to have, but on my cursor instead of an image:

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.05s ease-in;
}

img:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-120deg)
}
```

My canvas:

```
<canvas id="gamemap" width="900" height="526" onclick="animateCursor()"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
function animateCursor() {

}
```

css:

```
#gamemap {
    cursor: url('../Image/myimageup'), auto;
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648131/jquery-rotate-cursor-angle

Comment: Yes, i have already checked that link. And there is only an animation for the image element in the html code. I want an animation for the cursor image.

Answer (score 0):

**DIRECT CHANGE**

Just do `canvas.style.cursor = new_image_path;`

**STEP ANIMATION**
You could use an image array, containing list of images paths as string These images would be the same cursor image rotated at some angles by a step. Then, inside `animateCursor` function, do:

```
var img = 0, len = images.length, timer; // images is path array

function tick(){
    canvas.style.cursor = images[img] // new image every 5ms
    img++;

    if(img > len)
         clearTimeout(timer);
    else
         timer = setTimeout(tick, 5ms);
}

timer = setTimeout(tick, 5); // 5 ms
```

Comment: I have tried "Direct Change" but it only gives me the default cursor back.. Seems like the script not find the path. `"../image/myimage.png"`

Comment: @Jigfors Make sure to wrap it inside "`url`"s parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function animateCursor() {
  $('#gamemap').css('-webkit-transition','-webkit-transform 0.05s ease-in');
  $('#gamemap').hover(function(){
    $('#gamemap').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(-120deg)');
  });
  $('#gamemap').css('cursor','url("../Image/myimageup"), auto');
}
```